# how to do the dssc diff between versions with latest and latest-1 version

Tags: linux, synchronization, diff

I have to check difference between two versions for a file for many files. to get the diff b/w i need to dssc vhist and then i have to check what's latest versions and last but one version. then i'll get the diff b/w the versions. it will consume more time. any other way to in simple manner this thing.

```
dssc diff file_name -ver latest -ver 1.10
```

it's working fine. but i want to get the diff b/w latest and last but one verion like.

```
dssc diff file_name -ver latest -ver last_but_one
```

do we have any command like the above.

Answer (score 0):

so far the diff can be done via simpler coding:

`dssc diff file_name -ver last_but_one`

i.e. the specified version versus the latest one.